# InLine TeX input seems unstable

Tags: core-language, latex

In the documentation of version 12.2 there is a new feature to input TeX as mentioned by Stephen Wolfram.
See: [InlineTeXInput](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InlineTeXInput.html) in the documentation.

After typing CTRL$ you can type in some TeX, and then after pressing Enter the text is rendered.

However, trying to change the text in the box is unstable.
I create a Text Cell and enter some text, and then open the inputbox with CTRL$ and type
`\int y\, \mathrm{d}x`.
This works ok and after typing Shift-Enter or just leaving the text cell it will render.

When you want to make a change and go directly back to the TeX code, the front-end freezes and a popup asks to abort the kernel since it's not responding to the dynamic evaluation. There is no alternative to abort and doing so results in loss of your TeX which is replaced by `$Aborted`.

This is not always the case but after 3 to 5 times trying it will fail.

Any thoughts?

**Examples**

Enter TeX with CTRL$ `\int y\, \mathrm{d}x`:

[image: c1]

Edit the cell containing TeX:

[image: c2]

Front-end freezes until an abort popup appears:

[image: c3]

Comment: Same, using linux Fedora 33.

Comment: logged a support call

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Same using MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: Same in Linux ArcoLinux and Win 10.but wolframcloud work.

Comment: Same experience in RHEL 8

Comment: I found a temporary solution...if you want to edit, you can go to the "Evaluation" menu, then shutoff "Dynamic Updating Enabled". Click on the section you want to edit (selection should turn a diff color), then turn "Dynamic Updating Enabled" back on. It should turn the selection back to TeX which you can edit. When done, pressing "Enter" won't work...you have to move the cursor all the way to right (e.g. just hold down the right arrow). Now the EQ is edited. DONT CLICK on the EQ as you'll encounter the error highlighted above. This obviously isn't the most ideal solution, but it works.

Comment: Same issue on Windows 10

Comment: To add to chorus, same issue on Win10 for me too. My input was `o=\mathbb{e}^\frac{2\pi i}{3}`, rendered correctly but freezes for about two minutes before aborting when you click to edit the input.

Comment: @Lou, any answer from the support? Just upgraded to 12.2 and have the same issues (Win10).

Comment: I think it's solved or more stable in 12.3 but did not get any official answer.